# Calling a random integer into a function which is defined in on other function

Tags: matlab, function

If i have two functions:

```
//function 1
function [tp] = Calculate_T_P();

//body of function 1
// here I define U, which is a random integer between 0 and 15
U = randi([15])    
// say U is generated to be e.g., 5
```

Now I want to use the same value of U (i.e, 5) that was generated in the 1st function in my second function in a for loop:

```
//function 2
function [sp] = Calculate_S_P();

//Body of function 2
for b=0:U
  // body of for loop
end
```

Can anyone tell me how can this be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you plan on using these two functions.

**Option 1**

Pass `U` into your second function as a parameter and make it a second output of your first.

```
function [tp, U] = Calculate_T_P();

//body of function 1
// here I define U, which is a random integer between 0 and 15
U = randi([15])
```

and

```
//function 2
function [sp] = Calculate_S_P(U);
//Body of function 2
for b=0:U
  // body of for loop
end
```

So you'd now call it like this:

```
[tp, U] = Calculate_T_P()
Calculate_S_P(U)
```

**Option 2**

This is most likely a neater option and that is to pass `U` into both your functions and calculate it right at the start:

```
function [tp] = Calculate_T_P(U);

%//body of function 1, no longer define U here
```

and

```
//function 2
    function [sp] = Calculate_S_P(U);
    //Body of function 2
    for b=0:U
      // body of for loop
    end
```

and now your program can look like

```
U = randi(15)
tp = Calculate_T_P(U)
sp = Calculate_S_P(U)
```

Comment: Unless `U` is used in `Calculate_T_P` (or subfunctions) I would actually recommend against giving it as input. I believe it will even generate an mlint warning.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I'm assuming that it is, otherwise why would the OP have calculated it in there...